# How to prevent to load image of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**SORRY for Asking This, Because it already asked.**


Trying to prevent to load image of a div `.element` if it has class `.block` / `<div class="element block">` .

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="element">
<img src="images/picture.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/picture.jpg" alt="" />
 </div>
```

Mean prevent to load all images of `<div class="element">` when it has a class `.block`.
 
Don't hide, Delete image from html Node acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

You can hide it in pure javascript like this but you have to add id and not class to your element

```
document.getElementById("element").style.display= "none";
```

and in jquery

```
$('.element').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: How does this prevent loading of images?

Comment: you cant prevent images from loading you can only pass them dynamically whenever you need to load them.

Comment: @Mat. ok fine, so delete the node of html.

Comment: @Mat. Exactly so this answer doesn't actually answer OP.

Comment: @PeeHaa yes i should have wright more in my answer to explain him that this just hide the image.

Comment: @PeeHaa Is possible to delete image from html Node ?

Comment: Yes that is possible, but by the time you are removing stuff from the DOM it already has started the loading process

Comment: @Aabira you can look at this in reverse load the images whenever you need them only.